# Consume C# dlls in C++ for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, c++-cx, winprt

I have a windows phone 8 app created with Visual Studio 2012 - "Windows Phone Direct3D App (Native only)" project under Visual C++, and a library created with "Windows Phone Class Library" project under Visual C# group having target platform "Windows Phone OS 8.0". All I need is to consume the C# dll in the C++ code. The restriction is that I cannot change the architecture of the application, so the main entry-point must be in the C++ project, and from here to call somehow the code written in C#.

If I try to reference the C# dll in C++ app I get this error

> a reference to [dllname] cannot be added because the two projects
>   target different runtimes.

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080(v=vs.105).aspx , I tried also to reference the C# dll indirectly through a Visual C++ "Windows Phone Runtime Component" but again I get the same error when I try to add reference to the runtime component. I tried to change some project settings and nothing worked.
In all samples and demos which I found on the web, for WP8, the main entry-point is always in C#. Only some hints regarding windows store apps seem to indicate that could be possible to consume C# from C++, but I don't find any reference saying explicitly that my scenario on wp8 is possible or impossible.

Thanks in advance to anybody which shares the solution or any suggestion.

Comment: Make sure the proj architectures are both compiling for x86 ect...

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but the short story is that you can't. In Windows 8 C# WinRT dlls are full WinRT dlls that can then be consumed by any framework (WinJS, Native etc.) but not so for the phone.

On the phone C# can consume C++ WinRT objects (from C++ dlls), but not vice versa. You can create trickery by having your C# dll call into your C++ dll and pass around function pointers, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've liked this: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/C%2B%2B_support_from_Windows_Phone_8 . You may inject an interface into the .winmd C++ side metadata, that could be referenced and implemented in C#. Much cleaner than using delegates ... Still have to be initiated from C# ...